# Bootstrap UI slider for d3.js graph zooming ala OpenOffice Writer

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

We need to implement the UI slider component for the zooming in/out of  the D3.js graph.

The slider should look and behave like OpenOffice Writer zoom slider at the bottom of the Writer window. Example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/LibreOffice_Writer_3.3.png

We found http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ , but the functionality is very limited - the  common stops (50%, 100%) are not implementable.

Could anyone suggest proper Bootstrap or Jquery or D3.js component to start with?

Comment: Why are they not implementable?  Use a `formatter` for the tooltip if needbe.  http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: Its not about the formatting the tooltip. Its rather about configuring the "stick marks" for common zoom values (e.g. 50, 75, 100%).

Comment: Perhaps you can use this http://bseth99.github.io/projects/jquery-ui/7-jquery-ui-labeled-slider.html

Comment: Rob, thanks a lot. That seams to be the right one. If you put your comment as the answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: don't worry about it.  Just glad you got it sorted.